# Execve() adds two extra arguments

Tags: c, strace, execve

When I compile the following code and run `strace` on it, I can see that it adds two additional elements to the `args[]` array.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *args[2];
    args[0] = "/bin/ls";
    args[1] = "-lh";
    execve(args[0], args, NULL);

    return 1;
}
```

`strace` says that this is what is actually being called:

`execve("/bin/ls", ["/bin/ls", "-lh", "\340\301\361\267", "\1"], NULL)`

Comment: replace `args[2];` with `args[3];` and add `args[2] = NULL;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a null ptr to the last element of the argument array. Otherwise execve doesn't know where your array ends.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *args[3];
    args[0] = "/bin/ls";
    args[1] = "-lh";
    args[2] = NULL;
    execve(args[0], args, NULL);

    return 1;
}
```

So basically what you are seeing is execv passing random arguments until it found a NULL in the memory you point with the array. Of course it could be crashing as well.

Comment: Yes, it turns out argc in main() is redundant to, but more neophyte friendly than, the null pointer that ends argv!

Comment: I don't think is redundant, as (if I recall correctly) argv is not warrantied to end with a null ptr on every platfom, not even be a null itself.

Comment: @pablo: Your memory is faulty. ISO-C, sect 5.1.2.2.1 para 2, emphasis added: "If they are declared, the parameters to the `main` function shall obey the following constraints: — The value of `argc` shall be nonnegative. — **`argv[argc]` shall be a null pointer**."

Comment: @David good to know ! thanks a lot for the clarification.

Comment: In  [V6](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V6/usr/man/man2/exec.2), argv[argc] was -1. [Earlier documentation](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V4/man/man2/exec.2) didn't even mention the -1, and programs were expected to use argc. From [V7](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/man/man2/exec.2) onward, argv[argc] is 0 (NULL in the standards).